# Next quarter price when date-index is quarter end

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to calculate the abs change in price after a specific date. The data is quarterly and the end date is the last day of each quarter.

The code below works except where the date references the quarter ending in September. Then it returns null. It seems it would be easier to reference the next data point since the data is quarterly but when trying that, I get an indexing error.

```
quarterly_deviations_post_anomaly = {}

for key in anomaly_dfs.keys():
    quarterly_deviations_post_anomaly[key] = pd.DataFrame(columns=['1Q_abs_change'])
    
    anomaly_df = anomaly_dfs[key]
    q_df = q_data[key]
    
    for date in anomaly_df.index:
        if date in q_df.index and (date + pd.DateOffset(months=3)) in q_df.index:
            current_price = q_df.loc[date]['close']
            next_Q_price = q_df.loc[date + pd.DateOffset(months=3)]['close']
            deviation = abs((next_Q_price - current_price) / current_price)
            df = pd.DataFrame({'1Q_abs_change': deviation}, index=[date])
            quarterly_deviations_post_anomaly[key] = pd.concat([quarterly_deviations_post_anomaly[key], df])
        else:
            df = pd.DataFrame({'1Q_abs_change': float('NaN')}, index=[date])
            quarterly_deviations_post_anomaly[key] = pd.concat([quarterly_deviations_post_anomaly[key], df])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is there `pd.DateOffset(months=3)` on a date that is already the end of a quarter, if you start at the end of September and add 3 months, you'll get the end of December, this can cause errors.

Lets use `pd.offsets.QuarterEnd()`, it will offset to the end of the next quarter.

`next_Q_price = q_df.loc[date + pd.offsets.QuarterEnd()]['close']`

Comment: you welcome :)) dont forget to validate the answer if it fixed your problem.